# convert a long integer into class object using constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

I have to make a class which is internally defined as a vector of short values. vector initial size is 40. Now, I have to make a constructor which converts a user entered long integer into class object. otherwise, all elements of the vector should be 0.

I tried to write a code but could write till this level and now m stuck. 
P.S. i am a beginner in c++

```
class HugeInteger
{
  public:
    HugeInteger (long = 0);
    void output (ostream& outs);
  private:
    vector<short> v;
};

/*HugeInteger::HugeInteger (long = 0)
{
    int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<40;i++)
  {
    v.push_back (0);
  }
}*/


void HugeInteger ::output (ostream& outs)
{
  int i = 0;
  outs << "Values in the vector are initialized to" << endl;
  while(i < 40)
  {
    outs << v[i] << "\t";
    i++;
  }
}

int main()
{
  long integer;
  cout << "Enter a long integer" << endl;
//  for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
    cin >> integer;

  HugeInteger test (integer);
  test.output(cout);

  return 0;
}
```

Following error is there:

**Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall HugeInteger::HugeInteger(long)" (??0HugeInteger@@QAE@J@Z) referenced in function _main**

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters are explicited in the declarations, not in the definitions. Remove it from the definition, e.g.

```
class HugeInteger
{
  public:
    HugeInteger (long = 0);
    void output (ostream& outs);
  private:
    vector<short> v;
};

HugeInteger::HugeInteger (long) <--
{
}
```

Comment: I have already resolved that issue. Thanks anyways, but now I am facing another problem. See my edited post. Could you please help me fixing that?

Comment: You're supposed to post one question per thread. Ask a new question for the new problem. Anyway you deleted the function entirely, use the code I supplied above (without the arrow)

Comment: @Macro A. Sorry for that. I am new to stack overflow. Anyways, it compiles fine now but at runtime gives an error as 'Vector subscript out of the range'

Comment: That's another problem -> another question :)